# I am trying to run the r.reclass on QGIS and keep getting an indentation error?

Tags: qgis, grass

I am trying to reclassify a raster on QGIS 3.4 and I keep getting this error: 
`File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/grass74", line 1697
sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % grass_version)
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/grass74", line 1697
sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % grass_version)
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

I have tried to look into the file `grass74` and see if there is an issue with the indentation and fixed what seemed to be the issue but I am still getting the error...

help, please :)

Thanks,
Charlotte

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same error running `v.clean` on QGIS 3.4.2 on mac with `grassgis64` and @David S. is right there are spaces used in the executable which should not be there. 
The fix is easy: Open `grass74` in a text editor and replace the tabs by white spaces and it will run smoothly. 
I assume this is a bug on the development site requiring reporting.

orginal:

`elif arg == 'version':
[3 tabs         ]sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % grass_version)
        else:
            message(_("Parameter <%s> not supported") % arg)`

replace by:

`elif arg == 'version':
[12 white spaces]sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % grass_version)
        else:
            message(_("Parameter <%s> not supported") % arg)`

Comment: This was fixed in Dec 2018: https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/commit/bb2d070129bb810ad4a0f74dbc2c2ba8d0debc00 and is part of GRASS GIS 7.4.4 or later. Do you still use GRASS GIS 7.4.3?

Answer (score 1):

If you still receive the same error message it means that you have tab characters and spaces: both being used for indentation. Your editor should have a command to convert all of your tabs to spaces or vice-versa. Sublime's typeahead menu calls the command "convert tabs to spaces". It should fix this error.